# Adjective related to far west?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, nouns

I'm looking for a adjective to speak about things related to the far west. And more generally about multiple-words nouns.

Would far-west-ness or something like that be acceptable ? Is there a rule behind ?

Example for the main question : `Red Dead Redemption is a [...] game.` in order to say this game is full of references to the far west (but not that it was invented at that time).

Example for the general question : let's consider `cook book` as a noun. Can we build an adjective based on it ? `This library is a [...] place.` ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you edit your question to add a sentence or two that would include the usage you are looking for.

Comment: Cookbook is not two words but one: [cookbook](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/cookbook).

Comment: It would also be helpful (especially for those of us who have zero interest in computer games) if you would explain exactly what you mean by "far west".  Some of the answers assume that you mean the cowboy & Indian US westerns, but even in the continental US, there's farther west than that - San Francisco, Seattle and the coast between are quite a distance further west than that locale, while from where I live (western Nevada), Texas counts as part of the East.

Comment: @jamesqf yes, I meant cowboy & Indian US westerns. I'm not aware enough of US geography to be more precise. I'm glad your comment tends to avoid stereotypes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to use "far west" as an adjective, you can just say "far western." This is analogous to the adjective *far eastern* or *[Far Eastern](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/Far-East?q=Far+East)*.

But the the setting of *Red Dead Redemption* and dozens of [westerns](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/western?q=Western) (as a *noun*) such as *[3:10 to Yuma](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/3:10_to_Yuma_(2007_film))* and *[The Good, the Bad, and the Ugly](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Good,_the_Bad_and_the_Ugly)* and books such as *[Death comes for the archbishop](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_Comes_for_the_Archbishop)* is not

"the far west"

But the "[American West](http://www.theatlantic.com/photo/2012/05/the-american-west-150-years-ago/100304/)" or, if American is understood, simply

"the West" or "the old West" or "[the wild west](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2149899/The-American-West-youve-seen-Amazing-19th-century-pictures-landscape-chartered-time.html)".

If one wanted to include Canada and/or  Mexico, one could say

"The North American West."

The adjectival form of any of the above would be simply to change *West* to *Western*.

But *western* as an adjective with regard to these geographical areas, is largely used for books and movies, but not computer games. For instance, if I walked into a computer game store and asked if they had any 'westerns' or 'western games', they would probably ask me what I meant.

So one would probably have to settle for

*Red Dead Redemption* is set in the (Old)(North)(American)(Wild) West. Since Mexico is important in the game, it would be better to reference the North American West, or simply, the Wild West, since that term can include Mexico.

Also, since "western" can refer to both the western hemisphere and to western civilization, one would need to make sure that it is clear from context what you mean by "west". I expect you meant this by using "far west."  But in English we simply don't use this to refer to [the American West](http://www.cnn.com/2015/01/18/living/cnnphotos-tim-richmond-american-west/).

Also note that the current "Western USA" or the current American West might exclude some states traditionally included in the Old West or the Wild West. This is because these states are more central geographically. Although the city of Fort Worth, Texas refers to itself as "Where the West begins" and St Louis, Missouri is known as "the Gateway to the West".

Cook book is not two words but one: [cookbook](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/cookbook).

Do you mean a library that contains only cookbooks? You could say it is a library that specializes in cookbooks. Or a person could say that they have a *library of cookbooks* or a *cookbook collection*. I would tend not use "Cookbook library."

In many cases you can just use two or even three-word nouns as an adjective:

*mobile phone* app
*dining room table* centerpiece
*ice cream* scoop
*beer can* collection
*online league* draft
*horror movie* fan
*computer game* store
*Mexican food* restaurant

You can, in fact, make longer strings of multiple-word nouns used as adjectives:

Ice cream scoop
Ice cream scoop rinser
Ice cream scoop rinser parts
Ice cream scoop rinser parts catalog
Ice cream scoop rinser parts catalog page
Ice cream scoop rinser parts catalog page number
Ice cream scoop rinser parts catalog page number font
Ice cream scoop rinser parts catalog page number font size
Ice cream scoop rinser parts catalog page number font size finder
Ice cream scoop rinser parts catalog page number font size finder fee
Ice cream scoop rinser parts catalog page number font size finder fee war...

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is "western". There are a couple of things to note however.

In the case of:

> "Red Dead Redemption is a western game."

"Western" in this context could be taken at least 3 possible ways.

1. The game is of the [Western genre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_(genre)). Having to do with the American west.
2. The game was developed in the west. Referring to the continent of America.
3. The game was developed on the west coast of the USA by [Rockstar San Diego](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Dead_Redemption#Development).

It does not fit quite as well with your general question unless you are referring to something within an assumed area.

For example:

> "The library is the western building."

This assumes there are multiple buildings within a known area of which the library is the one furthest west.

This also works for the other directions:

> - Northern
> - Southern
> - Eastern
> - Western

Also, these can be combined as:

> - Northeastern
> - Southeastern
> - Southwestern
> - Northwestern

Note that in these cases, North and South are used first. You would not use "Westsouthern" or any similar combination.

Comment: As another note, in the case of "The library is the western building", this could also be taken to mean "[in the western style](https://www.google.com/search?q=old+west+library&espv=2&biw=1917&bih=958&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=3oMlVcuFHdLjoASzt4HAAQ&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAg&dpr=1#tbm=isch&q=old+west+architecture)" if the building is constructed in such a way.

Comment: This is a great answer. I cannot vote up yet due to my lack of reputation, sorry. Have you noticed the question about the cook book ? Is this building of an adjective impossible in that case ?

Comment: Yes, you can. One common way to do so would be to add "ish" as a suffix to the noun. For example, if you were comparing something to similar qualities of a cook book, you could say it is "cook bookish". An English teacher may slap me for saying that, but native English speakers have a tendency to play with the language a bit.

Comment: I thought of another suffix you could use as well "y". "Cook booky". Keep in mind, these are things you might say in conversation with friends or relatives. It is essentially slang. You may not want to say these sorts of words during a job interview.